# Running WP7.1 app on WP8 Emulator

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-8

Our app built for WP7.1 has been removed from market place. The reason given is "Your application does not function as expected on Windows Phone 8. Usability is significantly impacted". I would like to run the app(built for 7.1) on wp8 emulator to see what is breaking. Please tell me how to install a 7.1 app on 8.0 emulator? or please guide me how to approach to find out the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you already have WP8 SDK installed, its quite straightforward process.

In the same way you debugged your Windows Phone 7.1, you can do for WP8 also. Open your VS 2012 edition of WP8 SDK and go to open project and select your 7.1 project. Then you can run/debug it in WP8 emulator by pressing F5.

EDIT:
You need to test for all versions of Emulator one after the other, starting with the 'Emulator WVGA'

Comment: There are multiple emulator options available. Can you suggest which one I need to select.

Comment: It's different resolutions. Wiki the names for details.

Comment: Thanks. I ran the app and got some exception printed on my console. It is "An exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll and wasn't handled before a managed/native boundary". System.Number.ParseDouble is called in a line. That is where it is happening I guess. But I have no clue what is mscorlib.ni.dll and how how to proceed further. Does anyone have any clue ?. Note: The app works fine on wp7.1.

Comment: Try to explore a bit about that error and still if you can't solve it.. post another question with the relevant code which causing the problem